# Database dot com database syncing

Tags: database, cordova, salesforce, synchronization

I am working on a phonegap project to build a cross platform mobile app, and came to know from a website that the app's database can be deployed/built with "database.com".
The procedure is well explained but I have one question -

**how to sync the database available on database.com with a database on a local server?**

i.e. for e.g., if a client has his database (of his desktop application) on his local server and he requires a mobile app of the same now, what is the procedure to be followed in "database.com" to sync his server's database with the database on "database.com"?

PS: I need to use "database.com" for my database because I want to maintain it on cloud, and I do not have capability to maintain a local server.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a service for data syncing if it is to be more than once. I work on a project that does exactly this.

[www.overcast-suite.com](http://www.overcast-suite.com)

Otherwise, model your tables to Salesforce Custom Objects, export the data on the local server to CVS and use the [Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader) to import.